# jQuery get input value on button click

Tags: jquery, html

How to make input value showing every input on button click without deleting the previous input ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
    $("p").html(getVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>jQuery input value</legend>
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  </fieldset>
  <button id="btn">display value</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The example is working, the snippet works.

Comment: @AndrewL., check the question again. He wants to add the value **without** deleting the old value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Add the content to the previous content:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
    $("p").html($("p").html() + " " + getVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>jQuery input value</legend>
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  </fieldset>
  <button id="btn">display value</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

2. Use `append` instead of `html`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
    $("p").append(getVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>jQuery input value</legend>
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  </fieldset>
  <button id="btn">display value</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

You usage of `html` overrides the content of the `p` element.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean, append value as a history of values?

If yes, `append()` is the answer for it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
        $("p").append(getVal);
    });
});
```

Know more on it here, http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` instead of `html`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        var getVal = $("#inputValue").val();
        $("p").append(getVal); <--- CHANGE HERE
    });
});
```

[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
[html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

It's recommanded to add ID to the `p` tag and seperate  values with a space

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    var getVal = $("#inputValue").val() + " " ;
    $("#showInputValue").append(getVal);
  });
});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>jQuery input value</legend>
    <input id="inputValue" type="text" name="text">
  </fieldset>
  <button id="btn">display value</button>
  <p id="showInputValue"></p>
</div>
```